# R gerar série temporal com datas iniciais e finais para períodos de execução de serviços

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Estou começando a estudar sobre análises de séries temporais. Eu possuo alguns conjuntos de dados que são compostos da seguinte forma: cada linha consiste no atendimento a um cliente, tendo a data de início (menor data 2012-01-01), a data de fim (maior data 2017-05-01) do serviço, e o bairro onde ocorreu a atividade.

```
> mse_df
# A tibble: 484 × 3
       mse_in    mse_fim           Bairro
       <date>     <date>           <fctr>
1  2015-11-03 2016-08-11         Pachecos
2  2013-03-18 2014-10-02       Bela Vista
3  2012-08-08 2015-09-24          Brejaru
4  2014-02-24 2014-12-17            Madri
5  2015-03-30 2015-04-29  Jardim Eldorado
6  2012-07-30 2013-09-19          Brejaru
7  2016-05-24 2017-05-19      Frei Damiao
8  2012-08-13 2015-02-09 Ponte do Imaruim
9  2012-08-08 2014-07-23 Ponte do Imaruim
10 2012-07-30 2012-10-10     Caminho Novo
# ... with 474 more rows
```

Eu gostaria de fazer a análise de série temporal do serviço, com os dados divididos em 12 períodos por ano, e uma segunda análise de série temporal, também em 12 períodos por ano, mas desta vez por cada localidade, mas eu não sei como gerar os data frames de séries temporais para começar as análises.

Comment: Eu não entendi que tipo de análise está sendo proposta aqui. Tem como editar a pergunta ou deixar um comentário tentando ser um pouco mais específico? Por exemplo, qual o objetivo desta análise?

Comment: Olá Marcus, me desculpe pela imprecisão. Quero verificar se há tendências ou sazonalidades no serviço, e fazer previsão de frequência para os próximos meses, tanto geral, como por bairro.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo preparar df para as análises temporais que pretendo realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo aqui, já que não tenho reputação para comentar ^_^.

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer dizer, mas, segue aqui, como eu faria para criar um data frame com a série temporal de entrada, término, e saldo de pedidos por dia:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)


df <- tribble(
~mse_in,    ~mse_fim,         ~Bairro,
'2015-11-03', '2016-08-11', 'Pachecos',
'2013-03-18', '2014-10-02', 'Bela Vista',
'2012-08-08', '2015-09-24', 'Brejaru',
'2014-02-24', '2014-12-17', 'Madri',
'2015-03-30', '2015-04-29', 'Jardim Eldorado',
'2012-07-30', '2013-09-19', 'Brejaru',
'2016-05-24', '2017-05-19', 'Frei Damiao',
'2012-08-13', '2015-02-09', 'Ponte do Imaruim',
'2012-08-08', '2014-07-23', 'Ponte do Imaruim',
'2012-07-30', '2012-10-10', 'Caminho Novo')

df %<>% 
  mutate(mse_in = lubridate::ymd(mse_in),
         mse_fim = lubridate::ymd(mse_fim))

número_pedidos_in <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(mse_in) %>% 
  summarise(.in = n())

número_pedidos_out <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(mse_fim) %>% 
  summarise(.out = n())

dias_com_movimento <- número_pedidos_in %>% 
  full_join(número_pedidos_out, by = c('mse_in' = 'mse_fim')) %>%
  rename(data = mse_in) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0L, .))) %>% 
  mutate(saldo = .in - .out)

range_dias <- range(dias_com_movimento$data)

full_df <-
  tibble(data = seq(as.Date(range_dias[[1]]),
                    range_dias[[2]], 'days')) %>%
  left_join(dias_com_movimento) %>%
  replace_na(list(.in = 0, .out = 0, saldo = 0))
```

O último data frame fica com a seguinte cara:

```
# A tibble: 1,755 × 4
data   .in  .out saldo
<date> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2012-07-30     2     0     2
2  2012-07-31     0     0     0
3  2012-08-01     0     0     0
4  2012-08-02     0     0     0
5  2012-08-03     0     0     0
6  2012-08-04     0     0     0
7  2012-08-05     0     0     0
8  2012-08-06     0     0     0
9  2012-08-07     0     0     0
10 2012-08-08     2     0     2
# ... with 1,745 more rows
```

É isso que você está indo atrás?

Comment: Excelente, mas acho que o OP queria algo feito por mês, não por dia. Me parece que ele quer um data frame com duas colunas: a primeira coluna é o mês, a segunda coluna é o número de serviços realizados naquele mês. Além disso, me parece que ele também gostaria de outros n data frames similares a este, com estas duas colunas, mas separados por bairro.

Comment: Ola Guilherme, o que to precisando é bem como o Marcus mencionou, pq preciso verificar a qtd de clientes atendidos por mes, e depois por mes e localidade. Mas meus df originais apresentam na coluna mse_in o inicio do serviço, e na mse_fim o final do serviço para cada cliente, sendo que tenho q contabilizar a prestação por cada mes de todo o período de prestacao do serviço, e isso pra cada cliente. Qt a separar por dia é tranquilo pq depois da pra agrupar, o problema ficava em obter um data frame com justamente duas colunas, uma com as datas, outra com o volume em cada data. Agradeço a ajuda.